# Most simple algorithm to reverse direction on collision

Tags: pygame, collision

I teach Computer Programming. For first course students I'm looking for most easy algorithm to change direction on collide (with window frame). This is my actual code:

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()
speed_x = 1
speed_y = 1

black = (0, 0, 0)
width, height = 320, 240
size = ( width, height )

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
display_surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
display_rectangle = display_surface.get_rect()

ball_img = pygame.image.load("data/ball.gif")
ball = ball_img.convert_alpha()
ballrect = ball.get_rect()

while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

        if not display_rectangle.contains( ballrect.move([speed_x, 0]) ):
            speed_x *= -1
        else:
            ballrect = ballrect.move([speed_x, 0])

        if not display_rectangle.contains( ballrect.move([0, speed_y]) ):
            speed_y *= -1
        else:
            ballrect = ballrect.move([0, speed_y])  

        screen.fill(black)
        screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.delay(30)
```

**This code works fine, my question is if someone know about a easy algorithm or clear algorithm to reverse direction using `contains` or any other `collide` pygame test.**

Some times I think that an approach is most easy for students and a new clear approach appears.

**All suggestions are welcome**

Some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried your code, but it looks like it would probably work. What's your question?

Comment: @GregHewgill, thanks about your comment, yes, it works, I have edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is fine. Your code models the velocity of the ball using the 2-vector [speed_x, speed_y]. Bouncing off a (horizontal or vertical) wall involves negating the appropriate component of the vector.

As long as your students have a background in introductory physics (velocity, momentum, collisions) then your code should be understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code probably works ok (I haven't tried, but it seems fine), but I have mixed feelings about it. You check the x-movement then the y-movement, which is ok, but the Rect.contains() tests both x and y so it seems a bit redundant to me.

And depending on your students background, it kind of hides what you are doing.

I think I'd like testing everything manually :

```
if display_rectangle.left<=ballrect.left+speed_x or display_rectangle.right<=ballrect.right+speed_x
    speed_x*=-1
if display_rectangle.top<=ballrect.top+speed_y or display_rectangle.bottom<=ballrect.bottom+speed_y
    speed_y*=-1

ballrect.move([speed_x, speed_y])
```

BTW : why is it ballrect and not ball_rect ?

Comment: Thanks about ball_rect, I will fix it. If I check for both, x and y, at a time, ball returns from same way that it comes and this is not that we want (if ball comes from right up and collide with floor then only Y component should be changed)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Testing separately x and y is the way to go, but Rect.contains() will test both behind the scenes. In the end you tested x movement two times and y movement two times.  That's why I'd rather test manually the position like in my example code